# bootstrap Container not working correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with container. I have in container news and if one news tile is bigger it going into footer.

Like this:
[image here: container not working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGAxu.png)

I didnt find any working resultion

My code:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM gallery") or trigger_error("Vigane päring: " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
<div class="gallery">
<div class="restaurant-full-width block-events row">
<div class="container-fluid block-events" style="width: 1230px!important;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
         <div id="main" role="main" style="min-height:1200px!important;">
         <h1 class="clearfix"><?php echo $lang['koikuudised']; ?></h1>
              <ul id="tiles">
                <?php while($gallery = mysqli_fetch_array($db)) { 
                ?>
                <li>
                    <figure class="effect-marley">
                        <a title="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery-popup" href="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . 'system/timthumb.php?src=' . $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail'] . '&h=350&zc=1'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <figcaption>
                        <div class="brown">
                            <p><?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?></p>  
                        </div>          
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to create jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you give the "bage background div" (the main container) in your image a style of `overflow: auto` & let me know. *PS: Sharing your styles would help you get an answer*

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa overflow:auto; will make it scroll

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add cleafix div before closing the block

```
<div class="container-fluid block-events" style="width: 1230px!important;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
         <div id="main" role="main" style="min-height:1200px!important;">
         <h1 class="clearfix"><?php echo $lang['koikuudised']; ?></h1>
              <ul id="tiles">
                <?php while($gallery = mysqli_fetch_array($db)) { 
                ?>
                <li>
                    <figure class="effect-marley">
                        <a title="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery-popup" href="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . 'system/timthumb.php?src=' . $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail'] . '&h=350&zc=1'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <figcaption>
                        <div class="brown">
                            <p><?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?></p>  
                        </div>          
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can add clear:both css inline

```
<div class="container-fluid block-events" style="width: 1230px!important;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
         <div id="main" role="main" style="min-height:1200px!important;">
         <h1 class="clearfix"><?php echo $lang['koikuudised']; ?></h1>
              <ul id="tiles">
                <?php while($gallery = mysqli_fetch_array($db)) { 
                ?>
                <li>
                    <figure class="effect-marley">
                        <a title="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery-popup" href="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . 'system/timthumb.php?src=' . $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail'] . '&h=350&zc=1'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <figcaption>
                        <div class="brown">
                            <p><?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?></p>  
                        </div>          
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didnt do nothing. I checked my css and **.restaurant-full-width {
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}**